# using wordpress shortcode as href value in achor tag of html

Tags: html, wordpress

I have created Wordpress project and in that project, I have a one-course section and in that, I have enroll button there and the link to that button is dynamic which can be get updated via a specific post's custom field from Wordpress dashboard.

Enroll

I want to convert that shortcut to link in the anchor tag, how we can achieve it?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about your issue? Do you have any code that you tried? Anyway, you can render any shortcode with the `do_shortcode` function inside your php scripts: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

Comment: <a href="[xyz-ips snippet="Enrollcourse3link"]">Enroll</a>

Comment: As others have pointed out, you should use `do_shortcode()`. You may also want to consider just creating a new shortcode that renders the complete link as you want to display it.

Answer (score 0):

Altrough I'm still not sure how or where do you put your links, if you use PHP for rendering it's as easy as:

```
echo '<a href="' . do_shortcode('[xyz-ips snippet="Enrollcourse3link"]') . '">Enroll</a>';
```

Comment: I have used the php code sniplet plugin and created above shortcut by placing following php code ...........

Comment: $key_1_values = get_post_meta( 76, 'course3_enroll_button_link' );
foreach($key_1_values as $key)
{
    echo $key;
}